# Invalid Syntax on Python: "def method(self, (x,y)):"

Tags: python, object, methods, syntax, invalidation

When I try to run Python it says invalid syntax and shows me this part of the code: `def drawTitle(self, (x, y)):`. To be more specific the error comes from the bracket where `(x , y)`.  I'm using python version 3.7.

```
# writes and positions the title 
def drawTitle(self, (x, y)):

    font = pygame.font.Font("Chalkduster.ttf",80)
    textDisplay = font.render("Checkers", True, red)
    textRect = textDisplay.get_rect()
    textRect.center = (x, y)
    self.startWnd.blit(textDisplay, textRect)
```

The code doesn't execute and shows alert: "Invalid Syntax"

Comment: What is the result you are expecting from defining the argument `(x, y)`?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: first check, are you coding inside a class? if not then remove self,

Answer (score 0):

You can write the code like this:

```
def drawTitle(self, t):
   # x, y = t
   font = pygame.font.Font("Chalkduster.ttf",80)
   textDisplay = font.render("Checkers", True, red)
   textRect = textDisplay.get_rect()
   textRect.center = t
   self.startWnd.blit(textDisplay, textRect)

# call: drawTitle((10,12))
```